# Windows and Ubuntu on same VLAN, but only Windows connects to telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

Tags: networking, firewall, smtp, ubuntu-22.04

I'm having trouble trying to communicate with the port `587` on `smtp.gmail.com` on Ubuntu only, but the network and firewall teams (FortiGuard, I think), say that this is not a network nor a firewall related problem.

I have 2 virtual servers (separated VMWare ESXi machines) on the same VLAN: one is **Windows Server 2016** and another is **Ubuntu Server 22.04**.

`ufw` is disabled on Ubuntu (`sudo ufw status` replies `Status: inactive`)

Only Windows server is able to connect to `smtp.gmail.com` port `587`.

Is there any way I can find what is blocking this port `587` on Ubuntu? Are there any firewall or blocking application on Ubuntu Server 22.04 default installation, besides `ufw`?

**Tests on Ubuntu**

`telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`:

```
Trying 142.251.0.108...
Trying 2800:3f0:4003:c08::6c...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

`telnet -4 smtp.gmail.com 587`:

```
Trying 142.251.0.108...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

`sudo nmap smtp.gmail.com`

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-12 18:09 -03
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.30 seconds
```

`sudo nmap -Pn smtp.gmail.com`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-12 18:10 -03
Nmap scan report for smtp.gmail.com (142.251.0.109)
Host is up (0.0027s latency).
Other addresses for smtp.gmail.com (not scanned): 2800:3f0:4003:c08::6d
rDNS record for 142.251.0.109: cj-in-f109.1e100.net
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
113/tcp  closed ident
8010/tcp open   xmpp
```

`sudo nmap -p 587 -Pn --traceroute smtp.gmail.com`:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-12 13:50 -03
Nmap scan report for smtp.gmail.com (142.251.0.108)
Host is up.
Other addresses for smtp.gmail.com (not scanned): 2800:3f0:4003:c08::6d
rDNS record for 142.251.0.108: cj-in-f108.1e100.net

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
587/tcp filtered submission

TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT    ADDRESS
1   ... 30

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.21 seconds
```

`netstat -an`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.2.40.38:43550        91.189.91.38:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.2.40.38:56474        185.125.190.75:443      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.2.40.38:41044        10.2.40.88:445          ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 10.2.40.38:55294        185.125.190.52:443      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:47832         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.2.40.38:41222        54.217.10.153:443       TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.2.40.38:22           10.2.40.66:27284        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55043        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55046        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55044        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55042        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55047        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.2.40.38:443          10.2.40.67:55045        ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

`cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.2.40.38/27
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.2.40.33
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.2.40.62
        - 10.2.40.36
        search:
        - company.local
```

`ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:29:46:0c:7f:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 10.2.40.38/27 brd 10.2.40.63 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::29ff:fe46:20c:7fa4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(Edit to add) Also tested all firewalls status I could think of:

`sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: inactive
```

`sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`sudo nft list ruleset`

```
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

`sudo firewall-cmd --version`:

```
sudo: firewall-cmd: command not found
```

**Tests on Windows**

`telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP n11-20020a0568080a0b00b003a1f444307esm2174022oij.58 - gsmtp
```

`nmap smtp.gmail.com` (Using [Nmap Zenmap GUI](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows)):

```
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-12 18:15
Nmap scan report for smtp.gmail.com (142.251.0.109)
Host is up (0.029s latency).
rDNS record for 142.251.0.109: cj-in-f109.1e100.net
Not shown: 991 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
25/tcp   open   smtp
113/tcp  closed ident
465/tcp  open   smtps
587/tcp  open   submission
993/tcp  open   imaps
995/tcp  open   pop3s
8008/tcp open   http
8010/tcp open   xmpp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.72 seconds
```

`nmap -p 587 -Pn --traceroute smtp.gmail.com` (Using [Nmap Zenmap GUI](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows)):

```
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-12 13:57
Nmap scan report for smtp.gmail.com (142.251.0.108)
Host is up (0.058s latency).
rDNS record for 142.251.0.108: cj-in-f108.1e100.net

PORT    STATE SERVICE
587/tcp open  submission

TRACEROUTE (using port 587/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   1.00 ms  10.2.40.61
2   3.00 ms  10.2.40.6
3   13.00 ms 186.238.173.105
4   15.00 ms 186.201.241.153
5   14.00 ms 192.168.5.2
6   14.00 ms 192.168.5.2
7   14.00 ms 192.168.40.2
8   13.00 ms 192.168.40.2
9   14.00 ms 192.168.40.4
10  15.00 ms 187-51-216-237.customer.tdatabrasil.net.br (187.51.216.237)
11  ... 13
14  22.00 ms 108.170.245.141
15  21.00 ms 108.170.245.173
16  51.00 ms 209.85.251.92
17  50.00 ms 209.85.251.92
18  91.00 ms 172.253.64.37
19  70.00 ms 172.253.51.250
20  ... 26
27  15.00 ms cj-in-f108.1e100.net (142.251.0.108)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.51 seconds
```

`ipconfig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WP-SERVER
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : company.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : company.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-00-85-70
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e044:c9c3:a574:7f39%2(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.40.52(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.40.33
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 520228888
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-1C-CC-CF-00-1F-29-00-85-C9
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.40.62
                                       10.2.40.36
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: did you tried to reach your subnet via ping?

Comment: If I try to ping other machine on same subnet (example: `ping 10.2.40.52`) it works (replies `PING 10.2.40.52 (10.2.40.52) 56(84) bytes of data.` `64 bytes from 10.2.40.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.494 ms` `64 bytes from 10.2.40.52: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.532 ms` etc. But if I try `ping smtp.gmail.com`, I get no response.

Comment: Also, internet is working (for example, `curl -I https://www.google.com` replies `HTTP/2 200` etc.)

Comment: please add the relevant output always to the question instead of using the commantary section.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo.... It was the firewall.
It turned out that the firewall team "forgot" that:

1. There was a rule for servers, allowing just a few ports (like 80, 443, 21), and the port 587 was not among them;
2. The Windows server wasn't in this firewall group, so this port 587 wasn't blocked.
   They opened the port 587 on the server group on the firewall, and everything worked just fine!